# Numpy Array of Numpy Arrays. Reshaping not working as expected

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a np array of np arrays; each np array within it represents an image and all images have the same size. I want to reshape the np array to be just one np array with all the values. This has not been working for me. One of my problems was that when I tried to look at the shape of the np array of np arrays, I would not receive the shape information of np arrays inside.

```
# Example np array of np arrays. All images in the example should be 2x2x3. 
images = np.array(np.array[[[200,200,200],[200,200,200]],[[200,200,200],[200,200,200]]], ...)

# Assuming there are 3 images within, len(images) == 3
print(images.shape) # prints (3,)
print(images[0].shape) # prints (2,2,3)
```

For this reason, I tried to flatten the array and then reshape it. But there must be some issue with my math or something. When trying to reshape the flatten_images, I am getting a larger number of indexes for the np array than I expected. My math is width of image multiplied by height by color channels by number of images.

```
flatten_images = np.concatenate(images)
new_image_list = flatten_images.reshape(len(images), 2, 2, 3) #this is where the problem is
```

The original images array was a bunch of images of different sizes but I resized them all to be the same size. When they were different sizes, it made sense that images.shape would give just the first column information, but now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Your example is not valid python, please make sure that your [mre] is runnable (valid syntax, no `...`)

Comment: Yeah,  `np.array` is a function, and so `np.array[.....]` also make no sense.

Comment: If the images differ in size, you can use `np.array` to make an object dtype array of arrays.  But if you try it with images all the shape, the result is a multidimensiinal array.   Look at your array's `shape` and `dtype`.  `reshape` cannot change the total number of elements, whether they be objects (arrays), of numbers.

Comment: you shouldn't create a numpy array that contains numpy.ndarray objects. just use  list

Comment: instead of `len(images)` you can use `-1`.  Reshape math isn't fancy.  But don't make assumptions regarding shape and dtype.  Verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Some of the image arrays were RGBA format while others were in RGB format. This meant the reshape parameters given were off for those particular images as they had a 4 channel instead of 3.

I went through each image and converting an rgba images to rgb. This allowed the code to work.